# Renaming rows using pivot table function

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a sql query bringing in data with two column names, Model and Count. A table below shows a sample output of that raw data:

| Model | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 6 |
| C | 12 |
| D | 9 |

Using the below code I created a pivot table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Model', 'Counts'])
pivot_data = df.pivot_table(index=None, columns='Model', values='Counts')
total = df['Counts'].sum()
pivot_data['TOTAL'] = total
```

| Model | A | B | C | D | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 6 | 12 | 9 | 29 |

The issue I am having is I want to replace that blank text below "Model" with "Counts" however the way I understand it is pivot formats that first column not as actual data. I tried changing `columns = 'Model', 'Counts'`, but what this does is shown below:

| Model | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| Counts |  |

The below is what I want for my expected result/final table, so I just want to rotate the view of the table to read horizontally.

| Model | A | B | C | D | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Count | 2 | 6 | 12 | 9 | 29 |

Comment: Just change the df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Model', 'Counts']) to 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Counts', 'new_label'])
pivot_data = df.pivot_table(index = None, columns = 'Counts', values = 'new_label')
    total = df['new_label'].sum()
    pivot_data['TOTAL'] = total

Comment: @ShirinYavari Please don't post solutions in the comments; post an answer instead. Comments don't support fancy formatting, among other things.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The index of the pivot table is `Index(['Count'], dtype='object')`. Maybe different Pandas versions handle this differently? I'm using 2.0.1, you?

Comment: All comments and solutions so far have not solved the problem. @ShirinYavari This simple recreates the smaller table i explained above with Model replaced with Counts and nothing below it in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use:

```
>>> df.set_index('Model').T.assign(TOTAL=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))

Model   A  B   C  D  TOTAL
Counts  2  6  12  9     29
```

Comment: This reproduced the exact same table as I already have and also still does not have that 'Counts' Text in the box.

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with the expected output as dataframe constructor.

Comment: I just updated my question to show the desired output in tabular form.

Comment: So what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: I used your code and the 'Counts' word is still missing, which i mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: What is your version of Pandas? I used this code with your data and I get this output.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the dataframe first:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Model': ['A','B','C','D'], 'Counts': [2,6,12,9]})
 print(df)
```

[image]

```
 pivot_data = df.pivot_table(index=None, columns='Model', values='Counts')
 total = df['Counts'].sum()
 pivot_data['TOTAL'] = total
 print(pivot)
```

[image]

and if you want to transpose it:

```
transposed_pivot_data = pivot_data.transpose()
print(transposed_pivot_data)
```

[image]